# Getting Dashicons to Take on Hover Effect in Wordpress Nav Menu

Tags: css, wordpress

If you look at the top nav menu of http://www.footballpractice.org, you'll see that I've tried to add the dashicons in there using CSS classes assigned via Wordpress menu. The dashicon looks fine in the regular state, but doesn't take on the hover effect. What's the best way to apply hover classes to a :before element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is by applying :hover before :before.

```
div:hover:before {
...
}
```

For your website that would be:

```
.dashicons-megaphone:hover:before, 
.dashicons-search:hover:before, 
.dashicons-groups:hover:before, 
.dashicons-format-video:hover:before {
...
}
```

Although this is what you ask, it's not what you want. You want the icon to be included in the hover effect, and that's why it's better to set :before on a span inside the a tag.

Updated html

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span>Drills</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Updated css

```
.nav-header .genesis-nav-menu li a span:before {
  content: "\f488";
  font: normal 18px/1 'dashicons';
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

That will do it, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks! Going to try this asap.